# What is the pythonic way to skip parent method?

Tags: python, inheritance

```
class A:
  def open_spider(self, spider):
    #do some hacking

class B(A):
  def open_spider(self, spider):
    super(B, self).open_spider(spider)
    #something else
```

Now I want C to call A's method but not B's, which can be done at least in two ways:

```
  class C(B):
    def open_spider(self, spider):
      A.open_spider(self, spider)
      #do things

  class C(B):
    def open_spider(self, spider):
      super(B, self).open_spider(spider)
      #do things
```

Comment: There isn't a Pythonic way to do this, because it's not something you should be doing. Why do you need to skip over part of the MRO?

Comment: I bet you have a good reason not to, but just in case... What if C inherited from A instead of B? Saves you a lot of effort.

Comment: You could use Pythons name mangling `A.__open_spider` becomes `c._A__open_spider`

Answer (score 8):

You can do it using the second way. But I must say that part where child skips parent method and call grandparent instead is wrong and you should take a look on your design once again and think about it.

Comment: It usually better to explain why something is wrong rather than just that it is. Explanations will help people understand and enable them to think logically themselves instead of seeking confirmation from others.

Answer (score 2):

Use the second method; this is one reason why `super` *takes* a class as its first argument.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

As [Harry Percival states](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch12.html#_using_the_existing_list_item_form_in_the_list_view) in his book [Test-Driven Web Development with Python](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/pages/book.html):

> Personal opinion here: I could have used `super`, but I prefer not to
>   use `super` when it requires arguments, eg to get a grandparent method.
>   I find Python 3’s super() with no args awesome to get the immediate
>   parent. Anything else is too error-prone, and I find it ugly besides.

There, the solution he gives, is to call the grandparent class and its method directly.

Something in the lines of:

```
class C(B):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return A.get_queryset(self)
```

Which is your first method. I will definitely adopt it. Thank you!

---

This is an 'one-time' hack to temporarily override a method of a parent class. The intention is 'to do the job' until a refactoring takes place.

Otherwise you may have to rethink about the design of your classes as [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39918526/2996101) pointed out.

I had the same question and finally I came up with the following solution:

```
class A:
  def get_queryset(self):
    # Do not hack around

class B(A):
  from_c = False

  def get_queryset(self):
    if self.from_c:
        # Here goes the C hack
    else:
        # Here goes the B hack

class C(B):
    from_c = True
```

I [know that](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python):

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

I have a feeling that my "solution" is just a third way to a hack. However:

- I am not Dutch.
- To the extend of your example, this trick is complex and practical but not complicated

Comment: If you move your hack from C to B I'm not sure this is the right way to go. What if you had C1 - C5 classes?

Comment: @VladimirLenin I have updated my answer and provided a couple of links that promote your first method as a solution.